# How would I store and display a location on Google Maps using the address entered by the user and not the lat or long?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation

I'm using Android studio to make an app for an assignment, how would I go about having a location stored and displayed on Google Maps and stay there after logging out when the user is just entering their street address, city, postcode/zip code , country but not the lat or long co-ordinates?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert the address to a matching latitude longitude pair.
So if I would enter `Amsterdam`, it would return the latitude and logitude of that city.
This conversion is called geocoding. There's an [Android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html) for doing exactly this using the [Geocoder class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html).
If you want to just simple use the first value, here's an example with RxJava 2:

```
private Geocoder _geocoder;

public Observable<Location> convertAddressToLatLng(final String address) {
    if (_geocoder == null) {
        _geocoder = new Geocoder(_context);
    }
    return Observable.just(address)
            .map(new Func1<String, Location>() {
                @Override
                public Location call(String s) {
                    try {
                        List<Address> addressList = _geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
                        if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                            Address bestMatch = addressList.get(0);
                            Location result = new Location("");
                            result.setLatitude(bestMatch.getLatitude());
                            result.setLongitude(bestMatch.getLongitude());
                            return result;
                        } else {
                            return null;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error while geocoding!", ex);
                        return null;
                    }
                 }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```